# How should I import separate table in mysql database with foreign key?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I use Mysql and PHP and My database have constraint. I have made a function to import an sql file for a whole database by these step:

1. Begin transaction.
2. Read the file by using fopen.
3. Match and remove all comment in file while I collect a whole query by using delimiter ";" to an array.
4. Set check foreign key to 0
5. Drop or truncate all tables.
6. Run query one by one query element of array.
7. Set check foreign key to 1
8. Commit transaction
9. In case any thing else is fail (try catch), rollback transaction is trigger.

Everything is work fine. However, now I have to expand it. I have to make an import system which can import for individual functionality of website. It means I have to make an system can import individual tables and keep the constraint of them. For example, my system have tables user, article... when import article (export from local and import to development server) I have to check the user_id to make sure the application have this user (on development). I've never done anything like this before. I look like very complicated.

Therefore, I want to ask anyone how to do it? How many way to do it? and Which is the best solution to do it? Or If you have many experience, Could you please share to me where should I find to learn it or which book I should read to improve practice in database solution?

Comment: What should happen with the articles that have unexistent user_id? Ignore it? Show error? Anything else?

Comment: I don't have experience in this. But I think I will show an error message to end-user know and re-check their import file.

Comment: So you don't want to import any data at all if any article breaks the foreign key constraint?

Comment: Dude, language, language...

Comment: Sorry in case of my english is not good!

Answer (score 0):

You can switch off foreign keys constraints:

```
-- switch off
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- make import

-- switch on
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. However, If I do like that, I won't keep data integrity. For example, what happen if I import an article have user_id not available in my application development env. The user is created at local env and I just want to export article from my local and import it to app dev env.

Comment: You can set up beta stand with actual copy of real database for purpose of testing your migrations before run them on production server.

Comment: I have to make this functionality for other using it, not just for me. Therefore, I have to catch the problem break data integrity from another people.

Answer (score 0):

You can load your import data into a temporary table and look for invalid rows in it.

```sql
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_import_article;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_import_article LIKE article;

-- TODO: load or insert import data into tmp_import_article

-- select invalid rows
SELECT tia.*
FROM tmp_import_article tia
LEFT JOIN `user` u ON u.user_id = tia.user_id
WHERE u.user_id IS NULL;
```

If you get an empty result, then everything is fine and you can insert the data from temporary table into the real one.

If you get a not empty result - show it to the user in an error message.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you think this solution is same as using transaction?

Comment: You can use this solution with a transaction aswell. Start your transaction before selecting invalid rows and commit after inserting data from temporary table into the real one (if no invalid rows found). If you find any ivalid rows, you can commit or rallback - it doesn't matter in this case, because you dont change any data.

Comment: BTW: Don't use this solution as it is. You have to adjust it to your needs. There are other issues to consider - like duplicate entries.